# passing variables from Flexget make_html plugin to jinja2 template?

Tags: templates, jinja2

I am completely new to jinja and fairly unexperienced with python. I attempting to write a basic template that becomes used by flexget to automatically write an html file (using the make_html plugin in flexget http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/make_html ). I have written the template as below:

```
  <title>{{ tvdb_series_name }}</title>
     <meta name="description" content="{{ tvdb_rating }}" />
   </head>

   <body>

     <div id="content">
       <p>Why, hello there!</p>
     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

my problem is that when flexget is run I get an error as both the tvdb_series_name and  tvdb_rating is undefined but i can't find any flexget documentation to indicate how to pass in variables. I also already know it is defined as it is used in earlier parts of my config.yml file. Basically i am wondering if anyone has gotten this plugin working or there is a default way to pull passed in variables to a jinja template that I missed in the jinja2 documentation. Any help with any of this would be great as there's little documentation on flexget to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `thetvdb_lookup: yes` to the task, it will populate the entry with all relevant tvdb_* variables.

More info: http://flexget.com/wiki/Plugins/thetvdb_lookup

Comment: hey thanks for this, However I have already done this I use these variables in my config.yml to control where filenames and directory of output from deluge. However when using the make_html: command and selecting a template the variables do not populate and the log files says they are undefined.